# How to get back to viewcontroller in alertview

Tags: swift

I tried to get back to the viewcontroller when user press Go home in the alertView and it show me the error ( libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException )

```
 @IBAction func roundButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    //add alert
    alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Return Home", message: "Are you sure???", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let alertAction1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action) in

    }
    let alertAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Go Home", style: .Destructive) { (action) in

        let nv = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardidentifier") as! ViewController
        self.presentViewController(nv, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


    alertController?.addAction(alertAction2)
    alertController?.addAction(alertAction1)

    self.presentViewController(alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //end alert

}
```

Comment: Can you show me the Exception message? There's usually a message followed by the exception, just before the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide much information, there are a lot of possibilities. I will try to cover most of them.

Let's say that you are presenting the alert in `BViewController`. And you want to get back to `AViewController`.

If `AViewController` and `BViewController` are embedded in a `UINavgationController`, you will have to connect an unwind segue between `BViewController` and `AViewController`.

First, in `AViewController`, add this method:

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue) {

}
```

In the storyboard, control-drag from `BViewController` to the "Exit" of `AviewController and select "unwind:" aka the method you just declared. This is what you should see

[image]

Now give the segue you just added an identifier, say "unwindToHome".

In the `UIAlertAction` call back closure, initiate the segue:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToHome", sender: self)
```

And that's it!

If you are presenting the `BViewController` modally, then things are simpler, just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a [segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) on your storyboard between the two view controllers and give it an Identifier, then, on the completion handler of your alert action, you can trigger the segue. Something along the lines of:

```
let alertAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Go Home", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyStoryboardSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Good luck!